# I can't understand this notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image: Link to the notation specified]

What is an index set? , Why for each t (is a member of) T , A_t is a set?
How do I read the equations?

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Which black rectangle?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see it.

Comment: I only see three sentences in ordinary language.

Comment: Oh click the link

Comment: OK. I can  see it now.

Comment: An  index set is a way to differentiate the elements of a collection of objects (sets, in the present case). It's a sort of generalisation of the notion of `sequence`, except it's not necessarily linearly ordered, nor countable.

Comment: Ok how come for each t is a member of T , A_T is a set, with examples please?

Comment: That's because the author decided it would be sets. One speaks of a *family of sets*, indexed by $T$. But it might as well be a family of numbers, or of points inside a circle,or whatever the author pleases.

Comment: Well, I think that's why I couldn't understand it, I thought he was talking about a general rule, I didn't figure out that he was talking about a set of sets

Comment: "How come for each $t \in T$, $A_t$ is a set?"   What else would they be?  That's just information that you're given in the problem.  It doesn't need to be explained or proven.  That's like if you had a precalculus problem "Suppose a farmer has 400 feet of fence and wants to maximize the enclosed area..." and asked "Why 400 feet?"  It's because that's the information you were given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it would be denoted without resorting to an external index set:

If $X$ is a set of sets, we'd have

- their `union`: $\;\bigcup\limits_{A\in X} A$,
- their `intersection`: $\;\bigcap\limits_{A\in X} A$.

Comment: Ok that is clear, Lemme see if I get that right, So the set A used in my example is a set of sets therefore each A_t of it is a set right?

Comment: Exactly.$ $ $ $

Answer (score 0):

Consider a universe $X$ of mathematical objects, say of subsets $A\subset{\mathbb R}^n$. If you want to deal with "collections", or "families" of such objects it comes handy to organize such a family by means of a "hidden" function $$f:\quad I\to X, \qquad \iota\mapsto A_\iota\ .$$
In such a situation the auxiliary set $I$ is called an *index set*. This $f$ produces for each $\iota\in I$ a well defined element $A_\iota\in X$, whereby it is not required that $f$ is injective. The function $f$ as such is not interesting, it is just a formal mean to "organize" the family in question. Therefore such a family is then denoted by $\bigl(A_\iota\bigr)_{\iota\in I}\>$, and no reference is made to $f$ in the notation.

Concerning your further questions: Each $A_t$ in your source is a set, because it was said so in the second line. The two equations define the union (resp., the intersection) of a family of sets: It's exactly what you would think it is, even before you see the set builder notation for it.

Comment: Ok I understand, what about the other questions?s